# How to find the combination of the underwater safe in the Flooded District / Daud's base?

Tags: dishonored

In Central Rudshore of the Flooded District before entering the Daud's base there is a safe in the flooded basement of a nearby building. Where am I supposed to find the combination of it in-game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The combination is found in a letter, upstairs in the Rudshore Waterfront Upper Level. See this video on how to get there (relevant part starts at 01:29):

It is near the first Sokolov painting in the mission:

> There is a painting in one of the apartments lining the flooded main
> street (it might as well be a canal at this point). Stand on the
> pedestrian bridge and place the "Daud's Base" marker ahead of you. The
> apartment is ahead and to your left (the one with the balcony
> overlooking the water). The room with the painting does not have the
> assassin and the Station Key, but is the one with a Weeper.

[Source - IGN Dishonored guide wiki](https://www.ign.com/wikis/dishonored/Flooded_District)

The safe combination is:

> 4-2-8.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. None of the guides seem to mention _where_ the combination is from once you sit/swim in front of the safe.